# Java DB Web starter In Bluemix

Tags: java, database, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I am trying to run a [Java DB Web Starter][1] created in [IBM Bluemix][2] in my local [Websphere Liberty][3] server, but it keeps giving the below error

[ERROR   ] CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the openjpa-todo persistence unit in the liberty-IRDS.war module and the JavaDBApp application.
[ERROR   ] CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/openjpa-todo/entitymanager reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the liberty-IRDS.war module of the JavaDBApp application cannot be resolved.
[err] javax.naming.NamingException: CWNEN1001E: The object referenced by the java:comp/env/openjpa-todo/entitymanager JNDI name could not be instantiated. If the reference name maps to a JNDI name in the deployment descriptor bindings for the application performing the JNDI lookup, make sure that the JNDI name mapping in the deployment descriptor binding is correct. If the JNDI name mapping is correct, make sure the target resource can be resolved with the specified name relative to the default initial context. [Root exception is com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The java:comp/env/openjpa-todo/entitymanager reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the liberty-IRDS.war module of the JavaDBApp application cannot be resolved.]
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.naming.InjectionJavaColonHelper.newCannotInstantiateObjectException(InjectionJavaColonHelper.java:183)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at example.jpa.TODOListResource.getEm(TODOListResource.java:184)
    [err]   at example.jpa.TODOListResource.(TODOListResource.java:35)

Steps done:

- Create Java DB Web Starter in Bluemix
- Download Code
- Modify server.xml as suggested - Tried with both Connecting to Local Db and Database hosted as a part of Web Starter app-

  ### --Deployed application

  The `Server.xml`

  ```
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
      <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
      <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the   following element, e.g. host="*" -->
  <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

  <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
  <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>



  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
  ```

  ```
  <library id="MySQLLib">
  <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib" id="mysql-connector-jar" includes="mysql-connector-java-*.jar"/>
  </library>

  <webApplication id="JavaDBApp" location="liberty-IRDS.war" name="JavaDBApp"/>
  </server>
  ```

  Also Tried :To connect to DB in Java DB Web starter

  ---

  ```
  <server description="new server">

  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
  <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
  <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to  the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
  <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

  <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
  <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>



  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
  <dataSource id="mydbdatasource" jndiName="jdbc/mydbdatasource"> 
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
              <properties  url="db2://user13711:2gGhHNZvJwKc@75.126.155.153:50000/SQLDB" user="user13711" password="****"/> 
   </dataSource> 


  <library id="MySQLLib">
  <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib" id="mysql-connector-jar" includes="mysql-connector-java-*.jar"/>
  </library>

  <webApplication id="JavaDBApp" location="liberty-IRDS.war" name="JavaDBApp"/>
  </server>
  ```

Comment: can you please update your question with any relevant server.xml config and persistence.xml config?

Comment: Have added the server.xml and details in persistence.xml - These are as is file before modifying since even after all changes  the same error appears

Comment: the persistence.xml is incomplete, I don't see any of the closing tags

Comment: have removed that  to make it smaller

Comment: that's good that you use minimal code samples, but for XML be sure to include closing bits, just so we know what's all there

Comment: Added the remaining ones- just the headers left

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with the boilerplate app, the application is configured properly out of the box on bluemix.  It accomplishes this by turning on the `cloudAutoWiring-1.0` feature in the server.xm.  This will auto-wire jdbc/mydbdatasource to the resource-ref in the application's web.xml.

**To use the boilerplate locally:**

You need to take a few steps to wire the app to the server, since bluemix can't do that for you in a local environment.

1. Ensure a jdbc feature is enabled in the server.xml (which you have because `webProfile-7.0` turns on `jdbc-4.1`)
2. Configure a datasource in your server.xml with the jndi name `"jdbc/mydbdatasource" in the server.xml

Datasource config in the server.xml looks like this:

```
<dataSource id='mydbdatasource' jndiName='jdbc/mydbdatasource' jdbcDriverRef='myJDBCDriver'> 
    <properties ... />  <!-- depends on what DB you are using -->
</dataSource>

<jdbcDriver id="myJDBCDriver">
    <library>
        <fileset dir="C:/path/to/your/jdbc/driver.jar"/>
    </library>
</jdbcDriver>
```

As noted in the code sample, the `<properties>` you use depend on the JDBC driver you are using. 
For a listing of what properties to use for all of the main JDBC drivers, look at [IBM's DataSource configuration doc](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html).

Comment: Can this not connect to db created in Bluemix as part of creating the Boiler plate app ?In that case the properties will be that of the same right ? Also by any chnace can this be auto read from VCAP_SERVICES if we add that as the environment variable without modifying any files?

Comment: currently you can *not* auto read properties from VCAP_SERVICES into a local liberty instance.  You will need to manually copy/paste the properties you see in the bluemix console into your server.xml datasource properties.

Comment: I am still hitting error- updating the question with the server config tried.